# How to binary search in an array which is in an descending order?

Tags: java, binary-search

my code doesn't work, I want to be able to binary search in an array which is in an descending order.

```
static int searchDescendingGT( double[] a, int i, int j, double x )
{
  while(i!=j){
    // | >x | unknown | >=x |
        int m = i+(j-i)/2;

        if (a[m]<x){
        j = m; 
        }
        else{
         i = m+1; 
        }
    }
    return i;

}
```

What might be it's problems and what am I not seeing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binary search in a sorted (memory-mapped ?) file in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736556/binary-search-in-a-sorted-memory-mapped-file-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `foll` instead.

Assumption: `a` is your array, `i = start`, `j= end`, `x` is the element you're trying to find. `Foll` will return `-1` if `x` not in `a`

```
static int searchDescendingGT(double[] a, int i, int j, double x) {
    while (i <= j) {

        int m = (i + j) / 2;

        if (a[m] == x) {
            return m;
        } else if (a[m] < x) {
            j = m - 1;
        } else {
            i = m + 1;
        }
    }
    return -1;

}
```