# Using one text file to search through another text file in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to search through a file (File B) for matching strings from another file (File A). If the string is found in File A, then print the entire line(s) from File B and also update its progress to its corresponding JProgressBar(s) as the lines are being read.

The code below is working fine as expected, but the issue is performance. When dealing with large files, it takes about 15 minutes to scan just 5 thousand lines.

I'm really looking for a way to process large files for example 500K lines.

Please suggest if this can be enhanced to handle large files or which part of my code is causing the slowness.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.TextField;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JButton;

import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.LineNumberReader;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;


public class Test_MultiJProgressBars_MultiFileReads extends JFrame {

 private JPanel contentPane;
 private JTextField textField_File1;
 private JTextField textField_File2;
 private JProgressBar progressBar_F1;
 private JProgressBar progressBar_F2;
 private JTextArea textArea_File1;

 /**
  * Launch the application.
  */
 public static void main(String[] args) {
         EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {
                 try {
                      Test_MultiJProgressBars_MultiFileReads frame = new Test_MultiJProgressBars_MultiFileReads();
                      frame.setVisible(true);
                      } catch (Exception e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                      }
                 }
         });
 }

 /**
  * Create the frame.
  */


 public void FileLineCount (JTextField TexFieldName, JProgressBar ProgressBarName) throws IOException {
         File FileX = new File (TexFieldName.getText());
         FileReader Fr = new FileReader(FileX);
         LineNumberReader Lnr = new LineNumberReader(Fr);

         int lineNumber =0 ;
         while (Lnr.readLine() !=null) {
                 lineNumber++;
         }
         // Setting Maximum Value on ProgressBar
         ProgressBarName.setMaximum(lineNumber);
         System.out.println("Total line in file : "+lineNumber);
         Lnr.close();
 }


 public void ScanFileForMatches() {
         File My_Refernce_File = new File (textField_File1.getText());
         File My_Source_File = new File (textField_File2.getText());

         int F1_JP_v = 0;
         int F2_JP_v = 0;

         try {
                 BufferedReader F1_br = new  BufferedReader(new FileReader(My_Refernce_File));

                 String F1_br_Line;
                 String F2_br_Line = null;

                 while ((F1_br_Line = F1_br.readLine()) !=null) {
                         //System.out.println("File 1 : "+F1_br_Line+"\n");
                         F1_JP_v++;
                         progressBar_F1.setValue(F1_JP_v);


                          try {
                               BufferedReader F2_br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(My_Source_File));
                               while ((F2_br_Line = F2_br.readLine()) !=null) {
                                F2_JP_v++;
                                progressBar_F2.setValue(F2_JP_v);

                                if (F1_br_Line.contains(F2_br_Line)) {
                                        System.out.println("MATCHED --- File 1:"+F1_br_Line+" File 2:"+F2_br_Line+"\n");
                                        textArea_File1.append(LocalDateTime.now()+" : SYSOUT : MATCHED --- File 1:= "+F1_br_Line"\n");

                                } else {
                                        System.out.println("NOMATCH --- File 1:"+F1_br_Line+" File 2:"+F2_br_Line+"\n");

                                }
                                // Reset Progressbar after each Loop.
                                progressBar_F2.setValue(0);
                                 }
                                 // Set Progressbar to last value in the loop.
                                 progressBar_F2.setValue(F2_JP_v);
                                 F2_br.close();
                                 } catch (Exception e) {
                                         // TODO: handle exception
                             }
                 }
                 F1_br.close();
         } catch (Exception e) {
                 // TODO: handle exception
         }
 }


 public Test_MultiJProgressBars_MultiFileReads() {
         setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         setBounds(100, 100, 799, 568);
         contentPane = new JPanel();
         contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
         setContentPane(contentPane);
         contentPane.setLayout(null);

         progressBar_F1 = new JProgressBar();
         progressBar_F1.setStringPainted(true);
         progressBar_F1.setBounds(10, 96, 763, 50);
         contentPane.add(progressBar_F1);

         progressBar_F2 = new JProgressBar();
         progressBar_F2.setStringPainted(true);
         progressBar_F2.setBounds(10, 169, 763, 50);
         contentPane.add(progressBar_F2);

         JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
         scrollPane.setBounds(10, 264, 763, 109);
         contentPane.add(scrollPane);

         textArea_File1 = new JTextArea();
         scrollPane.setViewportView(textArea_File1);

         JScrollPane scrollPane_1 = new JScrollPane();
         scrollPane_1.setBounds(10, 409, 763, 110);
         contentPane.add(scrollPane_1);

         JTextArea textArea_FIle2 = new JTextArea();
         scrollPane_1.setViewportView(textArea_FIle2);

         JButton btnStart = new JButton("SCAN");
         btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {


                         // Call FileLineCount Method and setMaximum value on respective JPorgress Bars.
                         try {
                                 FileLineCount(textField_File1,progressBar_F1);
                                 FileLineCount(textField_File2,progressBar_F2);
                         } catch (IOException e) {
                                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                 e.printStackTrace();
                         }
                         // Call ScanFileForMatches to Scan files and Update JProgress Bars.

                         Thread t1 = new Thread (new Runnable() {

                                 @Override
                                 public void run() {
                                         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                         //ScanFileForMatches();
                                         ScanFileForMatches_TEST();
                                 }
                         });
                         t1.start();

                 }
         });
         btnStart.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
         btnStart.setBounds(684, 10, 89, 57);
         contentPane.add(btnStart);

         textField_File1 = new JTextField();
         textField_File1.setBounds(10, 10, 486, 23);
         contentPane.add(textField_File1);
         textField_File1.setColumns(10);

         textField_File2 = new JTextField();
         textField_File2.setBounds(10, 44, 486, 23);
         contentPane.add(textField_File2);
         textField_File2.setColumns(10);

         JButton btnFile_File1 = new JButton("File 1");
         btnFile_File1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                         JFileChooser JFC_File1 = new JFileChooser();
                         JFC_File1.showOpenDialog(null);
                         File JFC_File1_Name = JFC_File1.getSelectedFile();
                         textField_File1.setText(JFC_File1_Name.getAbsolutePath());
                 }
         });
         btnFile_File1.setBounds(506, 10, 89, 23);
         contentPane.add(btnFile_File1);


         JButton btnFile_File2 = new JButton("File 2");
         btnFile_File2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                         JFileChooser JFC_File2 = new JFileChooser();
                         JFC_File2.showOpenDialog(null);
                         File JFC_File2_Name = JFC_File2.getSelectedFile();
                         textField_File2.setText(JFC_File2_Name.getAbsolutePath());
                 }
         });
         btnFile_File2.setBounds(506, 44, 89, 23);
         contentPane.add(btnFile_File2);


         JLabel lblFile = new JLabel("File 1 Progress");
         lblFile.setBounds(20, 78, 137, 14);
         contentPane.add(lblFile);

         JLabel lblFile_1 = new JLabel("File 2 Progress");
         lblFile_1.setBounds(20, 150, 137, 14);
         contentPane.add(lblFile_1);

         JLabel lblFileLog = new JLabel("File 2 Log");
         lblFileLog.setBounds(20, 384, 147, 14);
         contentPane.add(lblFileLog);

         JLabel lblFileLog_1 = new JLabel("File 1 Log");
         lblFileLog_1.setBounds(20, 239, 147, 14);
         contentPane.add(lblFileLog_1);
 }
}
```

Comment: Both files are 500,000 lines? In that case, it will always be slow. If you have enough memory, read the files into memory. If you have duplicates, eliminate them.

Comment: can you use java 8? I think, Java 8 Read File + Stream will help.

Comment: Isn't the algorythm code O squared, i.e. speed 500,000^2 and will increase exponentially?  Can't you index one of the files to begin with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current solution is lineary iterating through *file1*, and for each line lineary iterating through *file2*. This effectively results in a running time of `O(F1*F2)`: The time it takes to run will scale ***quadratically*** by the numer of lines (F1 and F2) in your files. Plus *file2* is put into memory each time it's checked for a match, which is *very* expensive.

A better solution would be to read *file2* into memory (Eg. an *ArrayList*) and sort it:

```
Collections.sort(file2);
```

Then *file1* could be iterated as you currently do, and for each line use *Binary Search* to check if that String exists in *file2*:

```
for (String s1 : file1) int index = Collections.binarySearch(file2, s1);
```

Index would be non-negative if s1 is in *file2*.

This solution takes *linearithmic* time instead of *quadratic* and thus scales *much* better on larger inputs.

If you would like to improve the time it takes to sort, consider [MSD Sort](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/51radix/MSD.java.html) instead of `Collections.sort`. Only a minor improvement, but hey, it counts.

Comment: @SMeaden Yes :) - If that is a problem however, you could copy an implementation of binary-search into your code, thus not needing to import it.

Comment: Ok, just verifying which package so I could lookup documentation.

Comment: @Exfridos Excellent !! This approach worked like a charm. The processing speed is blazing fast. I am able to process 500K lines in less than 10 seconds. However i have a problem using binary search when using on fixed position / length files. For example, if the string i'm searching for is "TEST" and this string in lookup file is between some text "XXXXXTESTXXXXX" it is unable to find. How can i fix this using binary search.

Answer (score 0):

1. You could try to sort the rows in file A, i.e. the file you are searching in. This way, you can perform a binary search in it ([inspiration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736556/binary-search-in-a-sorted-memory-mapped-file-in-java)).
2. As a second step, I would create two threads:

   - 1 search thread, that will search in the file A
   - 1 reader thread, that will read the file B

The B-reader fetches a block of rows in memory (rather than a single row). Then it starts a A-reader thread, which performs a binary search while B-reader keeps going through B to fetch the next block of rows.

3. You could end the inner loop after the first match (if you are allowed to).
4. I would attempt to reduce the size of your try blocks, which may prevent some JVM optimizations. Even if performance does not change much, I don't see the point of including into try blocks any instructions that cannot trigger exceptions ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16451777/is-it-expensive-to-use-try-catch-blocks-even-if-an-exception-is-never-thrown)).
5. You should instrument your code to understand where it is spending most of the time, so that you can fine tune that part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

In a conversation on a very similar problem with [Madhulatha](https://www.linkedin.com/in/mandarapu-madhulatha-72bb6b2a/). She suggested an approach that turned out to be optimal. Below is the approach with an example

- Sort file A and file B
- co-parse file A and file B and find matches

[Here's](https://github.com/VaidhyaMegha/vaidhyamegha-knowledge-graphs/blob/v0.5.1/src/main/java/com/vaidhyamegha/data_cloud/kg/App.java#L108) the implementation of above for the problem we were discussing : Search contents of a file/table-in-db, which will grow rapidly over time, against a very large 1.7B row file which will also grow but slowly over time.

More [notes](https://blog.vaidhyamegha.com/?p=491), if you are interested.