# How can I search for a specific number/timestamp in a large sorted file in most optimized way using Java?

Tags: java, file, optimization, randomaccessfile

My file consists of logs. In which, every line is a log with starting column as time. All the lines in file are sorted according to the timestamp. I have to find out where the given timestamp occurs in the given file, file size could be of around 10gb. I can sequentially check line by line. Is there any way this can be done in optimized way to find the required?

Edit: I'm thinking of applying binary search. But what would be the approach I should go with to apply binary search on file? Can I use randomAccessFile class and use pointers? If so, How can I spot starting of a specific line where my pointer lands to get the timestamp of that log, thanks.

Sample log in the file:
2020-01-31T20:12:38.1234Z,field1,field2,etc,.....\n

Comment: If the lines are not of equal length, you cannot determine the line number with binary search, only the file offset.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Binary search in a sorted (memory-mapped ?) file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736556/binary-search-in-a-sorted-memory-mapped-file-in-java)

Comment: Hey, are all of the lines represented as Long values?

Comment: @Jason No, actually they're all text lines.

Comment: Well yeah of course but the question is whether or not all lines are comprised of values that can be parsed to a Long.

Comment: @Jason no, they can't be.

Comment: Do you mind showing the format of the file? Are all lines the same format? Update the original post.

Comment: @Jason, I updated the question with sample log line present in file. We don't know if they would be of similar length. but would be having same number of fields.

Comment: @Joe Thanks for that. Not the main answer, but second answer of that thread gave me solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1 (fastest):**

If possible, create another file that acts as an index for the file when generating the input. This could represent what index in the byte array each line exists at as well as the length of the line in bytes. You could even break this up into multiple index files.

```java
// 1 is line id, 0 is byte start index, 12 is end index 
1 0 12
```

**Option 2:**

A good solution would be a [binary search](https://www.baeldung.com/java-binary-search) implementation. This would likely be significantly faster than a linear search. The idea is that if what you're seeking is unequal to the middle element (line) then you're going to use the left half of the file byte array, otherwise the right half of the byte array.

Comment: I definitely second that. But How can i apply binary search with line numbers. how can i access specific line of file using line number?

Comment: How to do this without loading 10gb into memory? I don't think OP has 15-20 GB RAM (10gb file+object headers+...)

Comment: You could easily load chunks of the file at a time instead of the entire file @JCWasmx86.

Comment: The byte array likely uses the value `10` which is  `\n` also known as `new line`. You can assume the middle based on file size / 2 (roughly) and seek until `\n` is found in the array and find the given line and parse.

Comment: @suryaphaniteja Updated to provide another option.

Comment: @Jason Thanks for your inputs. unfortunately, I need to process files which are already generated. I don't have control of them while being generated.

Comment: If that is the case, likely a binary search with concurrent threads would be the best answer, to my knowledge.

Comment: You can assume that most lines are of similar length, right? So you can just seek to the mid (in bytes) and forward to the next newline.

Comment: Yup that's what's I'm suggesting.

Comment: Thanks codeflush.dev and @jason. If anyone could provide a code snippet of how to calculate offset and seek until the \n, it would be really helpful for me. I'm new to files concept.

Comment: You're better off doing the research yourself or asking another question with a small snippet of the file format.